# Por que o operador "delete" não remove referências a uma propriedade deletada em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem, objetos, operadores, delete

Eu estou lendo um livro sobre estrutura de dados em JavaScript e me deparei com a seguinte situação: por que `delete` não apaga um valor de referência? Vou dar um exemplo para ficar claro.

```js
const items = { a: 1, b: { x: 2 } };
const b = items.b; // Note que `b` não é primitivo, mas sim uma referência

items.b.x = 'changed';

// Por ser uma referência, `items.b` e `b` apontam para o mesmo lugar
console.log(items.b); // { x: "changed" }
console.log(b); // { x: "changed" }

delete items.b; // Por que isso não deleta tudo?

console.log(items.b); // undefined
console.log(b); // { x: "changed" } -- Não deletou
```

Na última linha, por que o valor de `b` se manteve intácto em vez de resultar em `undefined`, visto que o valor foi deletado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque o `delete` não tem a função de "apagar" a existência de um valor da memória, apenas remover uma propriedade de um objeto.

Da [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> O operador `delete` remove uma propriedade de um objeto. Se não houverem mais referências para a mesma propriedade, o valor é eventualmente liberado automaticamente.

É importante reiterar dois pontos:

- O `delete` não tem a função de apagar a existência de um valor, mas sim remover propriedades de objetos – tanto é que `delete` não funciona para apagar, por exemplo, variáveis locais.
- O `delete` não remove as referências à propriedade removida. Se ainda existem referências, o [GC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coletor_de_lixo_(inform%C3%A1tica)) não coletará o valor só porque foi removido de um objeto.

---

Para mais detalhes, consultar a referida documentação. O artigo [Understanding `delete`](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/) também tem algumas observações interessantes. E, claro, a [seção § 12.5.3](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-delete-operator) da especificação, que o formaliza.